# Opened Legendary Dragon Decks; wrong card order?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Hi guys I’ve bought the [Legendary Dragon Decks](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Dragon_Decks) pack from Amazon.

My problem is the order that the cards were in when I opened the pack was not the right order. For each deck the first few cards were in the right order. However after that the spells & traps came up before monsters. Most the monsters were at the end of each deck.

I have picture showing on the left the fake card and right the real one. As you can see the left on is lightly coloured.

Are these cards fake?[image]

Comment: Isn't the one on the *left* the one you pulled from your Legendary Dragon Decks pack? The other one ([YS16-EN040](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/YS16-EN040) seems to be from another set... mind clarifying (both seem original)

Comment: The one on the left appears the same on the yu gi oh wiki. http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Pendulum_Reborn

Comment: Sorry the other way around, the left one is fake and the right is real.

Comment: @MicolasKage updated my answer. I still think they are original.

Comment: What about the colour difference between them? I read that if Yugioh card is too bright, it’s fake. The left one is brighter.

Comment: @MicolasKage addressed that in my answer... it is of my experience that sometimes new print versions of cards tend to have slightly different colors, and this should be normal (Konami surely used new tints, newer paper, perhaps even changed the color code slightly). Just having a "too bright" card doesn't make it fake. Perhaps it's your card on the right (which was printed on 2016) the one that is a bit wore and more faded color

Comment: On wiki it said that, logically why would the cards be in different order. I’ve seen over 10 unboxing videos and all had the same order of the cards. Main monster followed by few extra deck monsters, then regular monsters and finally spells/traps and few other extra deck cards at the end. You should check it out.

Comment: @DarkCygnus and Micolas, one is American print and one is EU print

Answer (score 2):

> Are these cards fake?

**tl;dr:** No, they seem original. Cards may have slightly different details (like coloring) between different printings. Also, cards appear ordered by *card number* and not by card type.

---

**I doubt it.** Besides, I also doubt that Amazon would sell fake products advertised as legit.

You mention that the order were some monsters first, then spell/traps, and then other monsters. However, **cards appear ordered based on their card number, not by card type.**

The [Legendary Dragon Decks](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Dragon_Decks) cards have a **specific card number**, for example [Dark Magician, the Dragon Knight](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Magician_the_Dragon_Knight) is number "LEDD-ENA00". This card, as it is number 00, should come first in the order. Then number "LEDD-ENA01" comes, etc...

If we check the first link I included we can see that this is true. Some monsters come first, then a bunch of spell/traps, and finally other monsters, all based on the card number and ordered in ascending manner.

---

*Edit given card images:*

Judging by the images you included, I'd say that those cards **seem to be legit**. Be careful, as they are from *two different sets*, so the newest version (the one on the left, from the LEDD collection) may have slightly different coloring (as it's newer), but that doesn't make either fake:

1. We can see that the card number corresponds to the official one: *LEDD-ENC23*. The one on the right also displays it's corresponding number from the [Yuya Starter Deck](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Starter_Deck:_Yuya): *YS16-EN040*
2. We can see the dimensions fit, and all parts of a YGO card are there (type, the frames, copyrights, etc.).
3. The First Edition golden Millenium Eye sticker on the corner seems like the original ones (holographic). Do check both of them more closely but from here it seems ok).
4. The card code matches for both of them: *77826734*

Comment: I know what you’re saying about numbers, but the magician girl that comes after is completely different number like 31 or something. So that’s not issue, I also compared pendulm reborn with my own pendulm reborn. The one from pack was brighter than my one.

Comment: @MicolasKage was the box sealed? Did it was a verified Amazon seller? I feel that those aspects are not so on topic here (they should be taken to Amazon instead). If you got more details on the pack you opened would help: did the cards match the card number order (perhaps now you can't tell after sorting them), any details on the cards that make you suspect it's fake, perhaps a pic on one of the cards to give it a look?... otherwise I think this is hardly a fake product (will keep posted in case you reply, and keep searching other sources)

Comment: Yes and I don’t know if he was verified, he was 3rd party seller, however the box says made in Belgium. Dude this set comes in one order, and many youtubers have opened it in same order of cards. I’m returning it

Comment: @MicolasKage yeah, I suggest you contact them to find out about this, and so you get the product you ordered. If you need further help with regard to the YuGiOh game itself feel free to write a new question or update this one (if related)

Comment: Already have, and ordered another set, well that’s over $60 down the drain.

Comment: @MicolasKage sorry to hear that, although I wouldn't be too quick to dismiss this as fake products... take a good look on them, see if they match the official card numbers, artwork etc (we could help you discern that if you posted an example image of the possibly fake cards)

Comment: @MicolasKage I suggest you edit your Question to include such example. When editing the post you can include pictures (be sure to include good pics, ideally both sides). Or consider asking a different question if you want a post more specific on the fake/legit of your cards

Comment: "Besides, I also doubt that Amazon would sell fake products advertised as legit." Funny because Amazon has recently caught a lot of flak for shipping counterfit boardgames.

Comment: @Veskah well I was not aware of that news :) still, regardless of the source of that fact, we have to be careful not to generalize as these sorts of companies put great effort into maintaining a good image. Also, OP indicated it was a 3dr party seller, which isn't as "guaranteed" as Amazon's own.